# Efficient Sparse Matrix-Vector Multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to do matrix multiplication with a very large, but sparse matrix. I'm first mean centering the sparse matrix by subtracting the average row from each row. Then, I multiply this result to a vector. Is there some manipulation I can do to this expression to make it more efficient to calculate? I'm dealing with a very high dimensional matrix.

I'm reading into CSR representations of a sparse matrix, but I'm not sure how to compute the dot product efficiently in this representation.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting the mean would lose the sparsity. let's switch the order of operation around to take advantage of the sparseness.

Let $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, you are computing $\left[A-e\left(\frac1{m}e^TA\right)\right]x$  where $e$ is the all one vector, $A$ is sparse and $x$ is an vector.

\begin{align}
\left[A-e\left(\frac1{m}e^TA\right)\right]x &= (I- \frac1m ee^T) (Ax)\\
&= (Ax) -  e\left(\frac1me^T(Ax)\right)
\end{align}

Comment: How is this more efficient to calculate? I think you misunderstand my question. I meant to ask that you have a matrix $A$ that is already mean centered and a vector $x$. How can we efficiently calculate $Ax$?

Comment: Your matrix product now is sparse matrix multiplied by a vector.

Comment: Oh ok. And how do you go about efficiently calculating the product of a sparse matrix and vector?

Comment: $\left[A-e\left(\frac1{m}e^TA\right)\right]x$ is a dense matrix multiplied by a vector but $Ax$ is multiplication with sparse matrix.

Comment: you only add up positions that are non-zero, hence the complexity depends on the sparsity.

Comment: Oh ok. So if $n$ is the number of rows in the matrix and $m$ is columns and $d$ is the sparsity, is there an expression which shows the speedup for varying sparsity?

Comment: Suppose you know in each row of matrices how many are non-zero, you can actually count it isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, in the CSR representation, I have all nonzero elements and their locations (row,col)

Comment: yup, try to bound it?

Comment: Ok. I'll try to. One more question: if we want to add another row to the sparse matrix, and we want to update the result multiplication efficiently (without redoing the whole calculation again), how can we do that?

Comment: I do not know the fastest method, but I will possibily store more variables, such as $e^TAx$ in speed up future computation, Try to work out by introducing $B = \begin{bmatrix} A \\ b^T \end{bmatrix}$ and let your initial answer be $v$ and see how much you can simplify.

Comment: But, won't you have to redo the whole calculation, because instead of $m$, you have $m+1$ now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82815/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-user12888).